# Four propositions with certain properties

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

I am following a course in intuitionistic mathematics and I have been given an exercise about intuitionistic propositional logic.

**The problem**

> Find four propositions $X_0, X_1, X_2, X_3$, such that the following hold:
> (i) For each $i < 4$, the basic formulas of $X_i$ are among $A, B, \bot$ 
> (ii) For each $i < 4$, $X_i \vdash_{NK} A\lor B$ and $A\lor B \vdash_{NK} X_i$
> (iii) For each $i<4$, for each $j < 4$, if $i \neq j $ then $X_i \not\vdash_{NI} X_j$

Here $NK$ denotes the natural deduction scheme in classical logic and $NI$ the natural deduction scheme in intuitionistic logic.

**Attemps**

I am at a point where I have four propositions but recently I have found that (iii) does not hold.

- $X_0 = ((\neg\neg A \to A) \land A) \lor ((\neg\neg B\to B) \land B)$
- $X_1 = \neg A \to B$
- $X_2 = \neg B \to A$
- $X_3 = \neg\neg A \lor \neg\neg B$

Here it can be shown that $X_0 \vdash_{NI} X_3$ and for all the other combinations, I can find Kripke models to show the statements are intuitionistically not valid. Besides these four, there were other candidates that are classically equivalent to $A\lor B$ which were considered such as $A\lor B, \neg\neg(A\lor B)$ and $((A\to B)\to B) \land ((B\to A) \to A)$. Yet combining these have failed to give a satisfying result.

My question therefore is, are there other propositions that are classically equivalent to $A\lor B$ which I have not considered and cannot intuitionistically be proven assuming that proposition?

Comment: Hint: can you express $A \vee B$ in classical logic by a simple formula which only uses implication?

Comment: I can only think of either $(A\to B)\to B$ and $(B\to A)\to A$. Are these what you mean or are there different propositions?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. Now you can try comparing these with what you have. Also, note that in addition to $\neg \neg A \vee \neg \neg B$ you have, in the same spirit, $\neg \neg A \vee B$ and $A \vee \neg \neg B$.